# Text isn't anxiously aligned in span

Tags: html, css

The text-align (center) property isn't properly working for my text.
I have the following code:

```
 <span class="info">&nbsp;i&nbsp;<span id="uitleg_itje">Bla bla. 
 </span></span>
```

And the css for the `info` class is:

```
 .info {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #C73C3C;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 21px;
}
```

And the current result is:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be due to `letter-spacing: 4px;`
Instead of this and `&nbsp;`, you can try using padding instead.

```css
.info {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #C73C3C;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  /*letter-spacing: 4px;*/
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 21px;
}
```

```html
<span class="info">i</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `div` above span tag.Then your text will come in center.

```css
 .info {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #C73C3C;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 21px;
}

div{
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
 <div>
 <span class="info">&nbsp;i&nbsp;<span id="uitleg_itje">Bla bla. 
 </span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's right. Spans are inline and therefore inherit width from their content. Divs are 100% width by default